# How to make new df columns using pandas to get column names and values using regex?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, group-by

I have a columns like this:

```
**col_3**
MD01_TK336_AT000_PT01
MD01_TK336_AT000_PB250_PT03
MD01_TK336_AT025_PT01
MD01_TK336_AT000_TH005_PT01
MD01_TK336_AT000_SB250_PT01_BP04
```

within a pandas df. Note that other columns within the same row shouldn't be forgotten about - they are related to one other. I want to create a more df columns to get the following result:

```
**MD  TK    AT  PT   PB   SB   TH  BP**
01  336  000  01
01  336  000  03  250
01  336  025  01
01  336  000  01             01
01  336  000  01       250       04
```

where the non-existing values would just be blank or ''.

I have tried using:

```
df.col_3.str.extractall(r'([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)')
```

but it gives something like a groupby structure, and unstacking it doesn't give column names based on the characters.

**Edit:** based on Peter's answer.

```
Starting with:

**col_2**
MD01_TK336_AT000_PT01
MD01_TK336_AT000_PT02

>>> col_2.str.extractall(r'([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)')

       0    1
   match
0  0      MD   01
   1      TK  336
   2      AT  000
   3      PT   01
1  0      MD   01
   1      TK  336
   2      AT  000
   3      PT   02

>>> col_2.str.extractall(r'([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)')
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

     0    1
0   MD   01
0   TK  336
0   AT  000
0   PT   01
1   MD   01
1   TK  336
1   AT  000
1   PT   02

>>> col_2.str.extractall(r'([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)')
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .set_index(0, append=True)

         1
   0
0  MD   01
   TK  336
   AT  000
   PT   01
1  MD   01
   TK  336
   AT  000
   PT   02

>>> col_2.str.extractall(r'([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)')
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .set_index(0, append=True)
         .unstack()

      1
0    AT  MD   PB  PT   TK
0   000  01  NaN  01  336
1   000  01  NaN  02  336
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your attempt:

```
# Hard-code desired column order
cols = ['MD', 'TK', 'AT', 'PT', 'PB', 'SB', 'TH', 'BP']

res = (df.col_3
         .str.extractall(r'([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)')
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .set_index(0, append=True)
         .unstack()
         .fillna(0))

res.columns = res.columns.droplevel(None)

res = res[cols]
del res.columns.name

res

0  MD   TK   AT  PT   PB   SB   TH  BP
0  01  336  000  01    0    0    0   0
1  01  336  000  03  250    0    0   0
2  01  336  025  01    0    0    0   0
3  01  336  000  01    0    0  005   0
4  01  336  000  01    0  250    0  04
```